# How to set package.json configurations using kotlin-frontend-plugin

Tags: gradle, npm, webpack, kotlin

I want the auto-generated package.json to be configured in a way that it points to the Kotlin generated JavaScript file.  This is my current gradle configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-js'
apply from: "$project.rootDir/gradle/deploy.gradle"


dependencies {
               expectedBy project(":")

               // Compile/implementation dependencies
               implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.frontend'

compileKotlin2Js {
                    kotlinOptions.metaInfo = true
                    kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
                    kotlinOptions.moduleKind = 'commonjs'
}

kotlinFrontend {
                    sourceMaps = true

                    npm {
                           dependency("kotlin")
                           replaceVersion("kotlin-js-library", "1.1.0")
                    }

                    define "PRODUCTION", true

                    webpackBundle {
                                      bundleName = "${project.name}"
                                      sourceMapEnabled = true
                    }
}
```

This outputs both a myProject.js file located in $project.builDir.path/classes/nain  which is what I hoped would be reflected in the generated package.json file.  But the outputted package.json file (located in the project's build directory) is like this:

```
{
    "name": "myProject",
    "version": "1.2.0-10-SNAPSHOT",
    "description": "simple description",
    "main": "myProject",
    "dependencies": {
         "kotlin": "*"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "*",
        "webpack-dev-server": "*",
        "source-map-loader": "*",
        "karma": "*",
        "qunitjs": "1.23.1",
        "karma-qunit": "*",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader": "*",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "*",
        "phantomjs-prebuilt": "*",
        "karma-webpack": "*"
    }
}
```

The problem is this, the "main" attribute in the package.json does not point to the bundle file located in classes/main/myProject.js.  I tried looking through the documentation to find how to set the main attribute to the to a specific directory and js file but could not find it.  I can only change the name by setting bundleName property in webpackBundle portion of the gradle file.  Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I have tried to set in the gradle file the compileKotlin2Js as follows:

compileKotlin2Js {
    kotlinOptions.metaInfo = true
    kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
    kotlinOptions.moduleKind = 'commonjs'
    kotlinOptions.outputFile = "$project.buildDir.path/${project.name}.js"
}

But it results in an error:

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.  -configuration.resolve.modules[0] should not be empty

Answer (score 0):

So I found a work around to be able to use gradle to publish to npm.  I added the following bit to my code:

```
apply plugin: "com.moowork.node"

//Must copy the output javascript file
//to the location that the package.json expects it to be
//This is semi-workaround since I have not found a way to
//configure the outputted package.json file
task copyJSFile(type: Copy){

    from "$project.buildDir.path/classes/main/"
    into "${project.buildDir}"
    include "*.js"
}

//We publish our project to npm
task npmPublish(dependsOn: copyJSFile, type: NpmTask) {
    description = "publishes the project to npm"
    workingDir = file("${project.buildDir}")
    args = ['publish']
}
```

What this does is copy the outputted JavaScript generated files to a place where the package.json is configured when you call the npmPublish gradle task.